# A circular reference was detected while serializing with Json.Encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have situation where Json.Encode is working locally (localhost) which is 64bit iis7 windows 7 box.

If I deploy to windows 2003 32 bit IIS6 I get circular reference errors.  Shown below 'Error here' is the line where the error starts.

```
@*var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';*@ <<<<Error here
var model = '@Html.GetJson(Model)';
```

As part of trying to resolve this I thought maybe one of the project dll's that were being used on the server was different than that locally so i copied any reference dll to the server bin directory.  This did not help.

I do have a fix which is pretty easy.  I would have preferred to be able to identity the issue.  My guess is that it is using some dll on the server differently than locally to return json via Json.Encode then on the server.

My resolution as shown 2nd line above is to use Json.Net and a mvc helper

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetJson(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ViewModel vm)
{
    string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
    return new MvcHtmlString(s);
}
```

Has anyone seen this and resolved? (without json.net)

Comment: Please, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic/6613834#6613834

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Entity Framework, taking a look at the entities developed by the framework will shed some light on the topic. For example, I had table called Sessions and one called Enrollments, the Enrollments table having an FK relationship to the Sessions table PK. This resulted in the Session objects having a collection of Enrollments, and the Enrollment objects having a virtual instance of the Session that the enrollment was for ... which in turn pointed to a collection of Enrollments etc ... you get the picture, AND why the circular reference issue was detected by the json serialization.

The solution was to NOT query a collection of Session objects in the code, but to query an anonymous (untyped) object with all the same fields in it instead. The prevents the Json.Encode() from getting confused about, since it doesn't know about, the circular reference that Entity Framework is OK with in the code behind / server side code.